# Programa não retorna ao laço após executar função

Tags: javascript, node.js, promises, puppeteer

Tenho um robô que acessa um sistema online e faz downloads dos arquivos.
Ele funciona com um delay entre um download e outro, porém está demandando tempo.

Nesse sistema, eu só posso fechar a aba aberta após o arquivo baixado.

Para isso estou fazendo a verificação se em 25 segundos (esse tempo será alterado) o arquivo de determinada unidade é baixado, senão ele muda a unidade para baixar um novo arquivo.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fsReadDirRecGen = require('fs-readdir-rec-gen');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const { resolve } = require('path');
const { rejects } = require('assert');
const savedFolder = '/pasta_para_salvar_arquivos/'; 
const downloadFolder = '/pasta_downloads_win/'; 
const dirChrome = '/pasta_chrome_instalado/'; 
const prefix = "PrefixoArquivo";


var unidades = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', ...]; //array de unidades
var n = 0;

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        defaultViewport: null,
        executablePath: dirChrome,
        args: ['--start-maximized']
    })


    //ABERTURA DA PÁGINA
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 768 });
    await page.goto('https://sistema.com.br/'); //acessa o sistema
    .
    .
    .


    for (n = 0; n < unidades.length; n++) 
    {

        var unidadegen = unidades[n];

        
        await page.type('input[name="f2"]', unidadegen, { delay: 100 }); // AQUI SELECIONA A UNIDADE
        
        const pageTarget = page.target();
        const newTarget = await browser.waitForTarget(target => target.opener() === pageTarget);
        const newPage = await newTarget.page(); // AQUI ABRE A NOVA ABA
        
        .
        .
        .
        
        await newPage.keyboard.press('Enter', { delay: 100 }); // AQUI É O SUBMIT DO FORMULÁRIO E O INÍCIO DO DOWNLOAD
        
        // await delay(60000); // Eu fazia um timeout de 1 minuto para fechar a aba, por isso criei a função abaixo

        await checkFile(fileVerify(prefix, unidadegen)); // CHAMA A FUNÇÃO PARA CHECAR O ARQUIVO

        
        await newPage.close(); //AQUI DEVERIA FECHAR A ABA ABERTA PARA VOLTAR O LOOP COM UMA NOVA UNIDADE
      
        
    } 
    await browser.close();  //fecha o navegador...
})();


function delay(time) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, time)
    });
}


// FUNÇÃO ASINCRONA E RECURSIVA QUE DURANTE 25 TENTATIVAS (DE 1 SEGUNDO CADA) 
// FICARIA VERIFICANDO SE O ARQUIVO FOI BAIXADO.


const checkFile = async(fileExists, attemps = 1) => {    
    return new Promise(async (resolve, rejects) => {        
        if(!fileExists && attemps <= 25){
            
            await delay(1000);                              
            return await checkFile(fileVerify(prefix, unidadeArquivo), ++attemps);            
        }
                   
        resolve('OK');
        
    })
}

// FUNÇÃO SINCRONA PARA VERIFICAR SE O ARQUIVO FOI BAIXADO, QUANDO O ARQUIVO FOI BAIXADO RETORNA TRUE

function fileVerify(prefix, unidadeArquivo) {    
    var temArquivo = false;    
    fs.readdirSync(downloadFolder).forEach(file => {
        if (file.startsWith(prefix) && file.endsWith(".sswweb")) {
            var arquivoBaixado = downloadFolder + "/" + path.basename(file); //arquivo q foi baixado agora pouco
            temArquivo = true;
            var arquivoAlterado = savedFolder  + unidadeArquivo + ".csv";
            fs.renameSync(arquivoBaixado, arquivoAlterado); 
                                
        }        
    });
    
    if(temArquivo){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Eu excluí algumas linhas irrelevantes do código.

Quando eu coloco um console.log na função **checkFile**, ela está funcionando a checagem do arquivo durante os 25 seg, e quando é encontrado o arquivo na pasta de download o resultado é true, e a contagem finaliza.

O meu problema é que a execução fica parada após o processo, preciso de alguma forma retornar para o processo principal, que seria fechar a aba da unidade que acabei de baixar e continuar o loop para a próxima unidade. Eu creio que fiz algo errado com essa Promise.